# DBSCAN implementation in C

Tags: c, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I'm trying to implement a simple DBSCAN in C from the pseudocode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#Algorithm).

Making a more general use of DBSCAN, I represented my `n` elements of `m` features with a `nxm` matrix.

Some steps of the algorithm are unclear to me:

1. I can't figure out how to implement the neighbors points to a given point, useful to `expandCluster()`;
2. `regionQuery()` returns all points within P2's eps-neighborhood (including P); if I had a `nx2` matrix in which each elem has two features, I'd assume that the distance would be calculated as we were in Euclidean space and the formula would be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions); in my `nxm` matrix I have an `m`-dimensional space, so the formula to calculate the distance between two elements would be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#n_dimensions)?

Here's what I wrote up to now.

```
#define ROWS 13
#define COLS 4
#define EPSILON 250.0
#define MIN_POINTS 100
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double **data;
int *clusters;
int *visited;

int regionQuery(int elem) {
    // return all points within P2 eps-neighborhood (including P)
}

void expandCluster(int elem, int cluster) {
    int i;
    //add P to cluster C
    clusters[elem] = cluster;
    //for each point P2 in NeighborPts 
    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
        //if P2 is not visited {
            //mark P2 as visited
            //NeighborPts = regionQuery(P2, eps)
            //if sizeof(NeighborPts2) >= MinPts
            //    NeighborPts = NeighborPts joined with NeighborPts2
        }
        if P2 is not yet member of any cluster
        add P2 to cluster C
   }

}

void dbscan() {
    int i;
    int num_points = 0;
    int cluster = 0;
    // for each point P in dataset D
    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
        // if P is not visited
        if (!visited[i]) {
            // mark P as visited
            visited[i] = 1;
            // NeighborPts = regionQuery()
            num_points = regionQuery(i, cluster);
            // if sizeof(NeighborPts) < MinPts
            if (num_points < MIN_POINTS)
                // mark P as NOISE
                printf("element %d is noise\n", i);
            else {
                //C = next cluster
                cluster++;
                //expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)
                expandCluster(i, cluster);
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;

    data = (double**)calloc(ROWS, sizeof(double*));    
    visited = (int*)calloc(ROWS, sizeof(int));    
    clusters = (int*)calloc(ROWS, sizeof(int)); 
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        data[i] = (double*)calloc(COLS, sizeof(double));
    }

    data[ 0][ 0]=0.1; data[ 0][ 1]=0.0; data[ 0][ 2]=9.6; data[ 0][ 3] = 5.6;
    data[ 1][ 0]=1.4; data[ 1][ 1]=1.3; data[ 1][ 2]=0.0; data[ 1][ 3] = 3.8;
    data[ 2][ 0]=1.2; data[ 2][ 1]=2.5; data[ 2][ 2]=0.0; data[ 2][ 3] = 4.8;
    data[ 3][ 0]=2.3; data[ 3][ 1]=1.5; data[ 3][ 2]=9.2; data[ 3][ 3] = 4.3;
    data[ 4][ 0]=1.7; data[ 4][ 1]=0.7; data[ 4][ 2]=9.6; data[ 4][ 3] = 3.4;
    data[ 5][ 0]=0.0; data[ 5][ 1]=3.9; data[ 5][ 2]=9.8; data[ 5][ 3] = 5.1;
    data[ 6][ 0]=6.7; data[ 6][ 1]=3.9; data[ 6][ 2]=5.5; data[ 6][ 3] = 4.8;
    data[ 7][ 0]=0.0; data[ 7][ 1]=6.3; data[ 7][ 2]=5.7; data[ 7][ 3] = 4.3;
    data[ 8][ 0]=5.7; data[ 8][ 1]=6.9; data[ 8][ 2]=5.6; data[ 8][ 3] = 4.3;
    data[ 9][ 0]=0.0; data[ 9][ 1]=2.2; data[ 9][ 2]=5.4; data[ 9][ 3] = 0.0;
    data[10][ 0]=3.8; data[10][ 1]=3.5; data[10][ 2]=5.5; data[10][ 3] = 9.6;
    data[11][ 0]=0.0; data[11][ 1]=2.3; data[11][ 2]=3.6; data[11][ 3] = 8.5;
    data[12][ 0]=4.1; data[12][ 1]=4.5; data[12][ 2]=5.8; data[12][ 3] = 7.6;

    dbScan();

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", clusters[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is a C++ implementation that might help you with writing your C code (https://github.com/mhahsler/dbscan/blob/master/src/R_dbscan.cpp). Look for the comment saying "start new cluster and expand"

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. ()for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ) )

Comment: When calling any of the memory allocation functions: 1) in C, do not cast the returned value. its' type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for clarity and flexibility, declare a table to contain all the initialization values, then use nested `for()` loops to copy the values into the table.  This will make the code a lot smaller, faster, and much easier to understand

Comment: the posted code for the `expandCluter()` function does not compile. (mis=match on number of open/close braces)  A side effect of this error is the masking of the `dbscan()` function, so it is not seen.   Suggest fixing the compiler problems before asking about the logic.

Comment: these two lines seem to be comments, and missing the comment delimiters.  They certainly are not valid C code.  Suggest fixing the compiler problems before asking about the logic